# Is it possible to secure Apache Solr 8.5.1 dashboard page but not the query page?

Tags: solr

I am using Solr version 8.5.1 as a standalone application and would like to secure the solr dashboard UI with basic auth. I know that there is a built-in basic auth with security.json but when I do that all the select query url that is called from my application got blocked also. I want to leave the query urls open but only secure the dashboard. Is this possible?

I am using basic security.json setup found on https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/basic-authentication-plugin.html#basic-authentication-plugin

EDIT:
I saw this page [How can I secure Solr 5.3.1 only admin pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750045/how-can-i-secure-solr-5-3-1-only-admin-pages) but adding authentication in jetty.xml and web.xml doesn't seem to work anymore with version 8.5.1

Comment: See https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html - the `read` permission gives read access to most features by default, but adding a custom rule with `/select` that doesn't require authentication should be possible, then having password authentication for all other endpoints. The example given under  permission ordering resolution should be close to what you want. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html#permission-ordering-and-resolution

Comment: Thank you for the response MatsLindh but can you explain how would you add a custom rule that doesn't require authentication? I have been trying but no success so far. There is property "blockUnknown" that needs to set to be set to true for authentication to started working but this will prevent the request without authentication alltogether.

Comment: You ahve to set `blockUnknown` to false, then add a rule that blocks everything - `blockUnknown` is in relation to those request that doesn't match any of your rules (_All requests w/o credentials will be rejected with a 401 error. Set 'blockUnknown' to false (or remove it altogether) if you wish to let unauthenticated requests to go through. However, if a particular resource is protected by a rule, they are rejected anyway with a 401 error._)

Comment: Okay that make sense MatsLindh. Can you please provide an example of security.json you have in mind? I'm struggle to understand how rule can be applied to unauthenticated user. aren't rules suppose to apply to only specific roles? How do you apply rules to unauthenticated user?

Comment: I don't have a Solr instance available for testing right now, but I'm guessing you can use the wildcard `*` since it matches any role: _The wildcard * can be used to indicate that all roles can access the described functionality._ I'd try that first, at least.

Comment: Okay I finally got it to work. I took your suggestion to set the blockUnknown to false and I make sure to have at least one user to have "core-admin-read" permission. This automatically requires the authentication when attempting to login on the UI

Comment: Add an answer with your configuration and accept your own answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I finally got it to work. I took MatsLindh's suggestion to set the blockUnknown to false and I make sure to have at least one user to have "core-admin-read" permission. This automatically requires the authentication when attempting to login on the UI

Here is an example of my security.json

```
{
   "authentication":{
      "blockUnknown":false,
      "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
      "credentials":{
         "solr":"...."
      },
      "realm":"My Solr users",
      "forwardCredentials":false,
      "":{
         "v":0
      }
   },
   "authorization":{
      "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
      "permissions":[
         {
            "name":"core-admin-read",
            "role":"admin"
         }
      ],
      "user-role":{
         "solr":"admin"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the following to work in 8.8

```
{
  "authentication":{
    "blockUnknown":false,
    "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials":{"solr":"..."}},
  "authorization":{
    "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "user-role":{"solr":"admin"},
    "permissions":[
      {
        "name":"all",
        "role":"admin",
        "index":1},
      {
        "name":"open_select",
        "collection":"*",
        "path":"/select",
        "role":null,
        "index":2}],
    "":{"v":0}}}
```